# simple question: the eigenvectors of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, math-software, mathematica

\begin{align*}A=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\\end{array}\right);\end{align*}

The eigenvalues are $1$, I know one of the eigenvectors is $(1,0,0,0)$, Is that all?

The mathematica gives, why not {{1,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0}}?

```
Eigenvectors[A]
```

\begin{align*}\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\end{array}\right)\end{align*}

Comment: This is a question about a software package, not mathematics.

Comment: We have [tag:mathematica] and [tag:math-software] tags here, and I believe questions about Mathematica are considered on-topic for this site.

Comment: @realmatrix: Did you see the documentation and how you find the generalized ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got mathematica and in the documentation of `Eigenvector`it says

> For an n[Cross]n matrix, Eigenvectors always returns a list of length n. 
>   The list contains each of the independent eigenvectors of the matrix, followed if necessary by an appropriate number of vectors of zeros. »

So mathematica says you have exactly one linear independent eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $Av = v$; that is, $v$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $1$. Writing $v = (v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4)^T$, we find that

$$v_1 + 2v_2 + 3v_3 + 4v_4 = v_1 \implies 2v_2 + 3v_3 + 4v_4 = 0$$

$$v_2 + 2v_3 + 3v_4 = v_2 \implies 2v_3 + 3v_4 = 0$$

$$v_3 + 2v_4 = v_3 \implies 2v_4 = 0$$

Now back substituting leads to $v_2 = v_3 = v_4 = 0$, and so the eigenspace is spanned by $(1, 0, 0, 0)^T$.

Comment: why mathematica doesn't give the matrix consists of four vectors ${1,0,0,0}$

Comment: @realmatrix I'm not familiar with Mathematica output in this context.